# Put interfaces and concrete class in one file or separate them in different files?

Tags: typescript, oop

This question confused me for several years. Here are the demos:

**Put interface and concrete in one file**

`EmailService.ts`:

```js
interface IEmailService {
  send(mail: any): Promise<any>;
}

interface IEmailServiceOptions {}

class EmailService implements IEmailService {
  public static getInstance(options: IEmailServiceOptions) {
    if (EmailService.instance) {
      return EmailService.instance;
    } else {
      EmailService.instance = new EmailService(options);
      return EmailService.instance;
    }
  }
  private static instance: EmailService;
  private constructor(options: IEmailServiceOptions) {}

  public async send(mail: any): Promise<any> {
    // ...
  }
}

export { EmailService, IEmailService, IEmailServiceOptions };
```

Or, **separate them in different files**:

`EmailService.ts`

```js
interface IEmailService {
  send(mail: any): Promise<any>;
}

interface IEmailServiceOptions {}

export { IEmailService, IEmailServiceOptions };
```

`EmailServiceImpl.ts`:

```js
import { IEmailService, IEmailServiceOptions } from './EmailService';

class EmailService implements IEmailService {
  public static getInstance(options: IEmailServiceOptions) {
    if (EmailService.instance) {
      return EmailService.instance;
    } else {
      EmailService.instance = new EmailService(options);
      return EmailService.instance;
    }
  }
  private static instance: EmailService;
  private constructor(options: IEmailServiceOptions) {}

  public async send(mail: any): Promise<any> {
    // ...
  }
}

export { EmailService };
```

Which one is better? Why?

Comment: Usually you have interfaces and controllers in different folders, one class/interface per file named as that class/interface. It's because one interface can be implemented by multiple classes

Comment: Please explain why downvote and close.

Comment: Because you ask `What color is better: blue or yellow and why?`

Comment: I think it's not the same concept. You can say these two patterns are the same rather than close it. But actually, are them the same? That's also what I want to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to expose an interface to some other code you may have that interface in the same file as a class. If the interface is used by several classes you may want to put it into a separate folder/file as mentioned in the comments. However, there are a few cases that are needed to be clarified.

Typescript interfaces are slightly different from interfaces in other languages. From the handbook (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html):

> One of TypeScript’s core principles is that type checking focuses on the shape that values have. This is sometimes called “duck typing” or “structural subtyping”. In TypeScript, interfaces fill the role of naming these types, and are a powerful way of defining contracts within your code as well as contracts with code outside of your project.

So in case of `IEmailServiceOptions` it is totally fine to have `interface IEmailServiceOptions {}` in the same file as a class, because you only expect the options to be of a certain shape. There are cases when you want to use it outside of the class, for example, if you have some other interface that has a property, which should comply with `interface IEmailServiceOptions {}`. However, the file/folder with this interface should be beside the class (`EmailService` in this case), because the options is something that the class "depends" on.

As for `IEmailService` the situation is slightly different. You not just checking the shape of options that some method is accepting. You're binding class implementation to an interface. In this case an interface is not something that class owns or depends on, but something that the class is committed to (a contract). So ideally, if you put these kind of interfaces into a separate folder/file, the folder/file should not be beside the classes that implement the interface, but beside the class or something else that expects to use the instance of a class that implements the interface. It is especially noticeable when you're using DI.

For example,

```
// emailServiceUser/EmailServiceUser.ts
class EmailServiceUser {
    constructor(emailService: IEmailService) {}
}

// emailServiceUser/IEmailService.ts
interface IEmailService {
    send(mail: any): Promise<any>;
}

// emailService/EmailService.ts
import IEmailService from '../emailServiceUser/IEmailService';

class EmailService implements IEmailService {...}
```

So, as you can see, that `EmailServiceUser` expects and emailService to implement `IEmailService`. That's why `EmailServiceUser` provides the interface (the interface is in the same folder). Now we can create as many classes as we want to implement the emailService.

Comment: Very helpful answer. I think `emailServiceUser/IEmailService.ts` is not the right place to put the interface when there are many concrete classes depend on the `IEmailService` interface, should I put this interface into a separated file or directory? The directory structure like `interfaces/IEmailService.ts`, group by type. It's confused about how to organize interfaces and concrete classes when to use DDD.

Comment: If you're using DI, then `emailServiceUser/` (important thing it's close to `EmailServiceUser`) would be the right place to put the interface. Concrete classes will be in completely different folders and that's OK. Probably your `EmailService` should not be a part of the Domain Model, but rather the app layer. Domain Model should be self-contained (no connection to app layer). At this point I can only guess, since you know your application better than me, but I suggest you to consult Clean Architecture by Bob Martin (layered arch, DI) and DDD by Eric Evans if you didn't read them yet.

Comment: Also, there's Domain-Driven Design Quickly by Abel Avram (Author), Floyd Marinescu (Author) in under 200 pages. DDD by Eric Evans can be overwhelming sometimes.

Comment: Yes. I am reading it. It's a little hard to understand. There are few examples. And yes, I use IoC to manage DI as well.  This is a demo repo: https://github.com/mrdulin/gcp-task-queue. But I put the interfaces casually.

Comment: Firstly, I'd try to identify what should be a part of the domain model. Once that's done, you can put other stuff into different layers (anything related to rest calls). Then I'd just follow the rules specified in the answer above in scope of a single layer and use the rule that layers above should only have access to objects on a layer below them.

Comment: You can structure layers in the projects with folders. It should be obvious just by the look at it, where's what. I think that's all the help I can provide.